# Fancyhdr for reports

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, report

I want to use `fancyhdr` for the document class `report`. I want the page number to be on the left side for even page numbers and on the right for odd numbers. On the other side I want the chapter number. However, this only works for `\documentclass{book}` and not for `\documentclass{report}`. In a `report` it does the same for odd and even page numbers. Is there a way to make it work for `report`?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thechapter}
\chapter{A}
\newpage +
\chapter{B}
\newpage +
\newpage +
\chapter{C}
\newpage +
\newpage +
\newpage +
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX warnings should not be lightheartedly ignored; the code you post results in a warning which describes precisely the issue

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is
useless on input line 5.

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is
useless on input line 6.
```

By default `report` makes one-sided document, for which there is no distinction between even/odd pages. You need to pass the `twoside` option:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
```

Personal comment: I find the result (only page and chapter number, without "Chapter", or title, or whatever) *very* confusing. I doubt you readers will love it...